# How to design this in android?

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-recyclerview

[image: This Android Design I want]

I have a problem with the design of the picture. I have tried many ways to do this. I used GridView to make a similar thing. But in GridView rows columns are equal. Please help me to do this. Suggest me some XML to design a layout like this image.

Comment: Use a GridLayout instead of a GridView: the cells can have different sizes.

Answer (score 1):

You can use staggered grid. Use RecyclerView with StaggeredGridLayoutManager.

Check this example:
https://inducesmile.com/android/android-staggeredgridlayoutmanager-example-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

You can Use RecyclerView to make this kind of layout.

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html

Answer (score 0):

By using [staggeredgridview](https://github.com/etsy/AndroidStaggeredGrid) You can acheive this layout